# I would like to make sync.com app appear early on sharing

Tags: ios, sharing

I have sync from sync.com installed. When I want to add photos to share.com I press the share button. Then I get a selection of apps to share with. Sync.com app appears at the very end and I would like to move the app up to be one of the first apps or the first apps. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We might need a screen image to understand what you want to change. Feel free to use the edit control to add details. See [ask] if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after using sync.com the third time it was automatically prioritized. So I answered the question myself, but I want to keep this as maybe others have the same question.